# Update a chart automatically with a timer

Tags: vb.net

So, I am developing an application and I got stuck probably on a basic thing that I can't solve. I have a chart which is connected to a database and it will be running a query. I was able to do it, but the issue there I am facing is that it won't update unless I close and open the application.

I will show you the code that I am using and then explain it:

```
Public Sub UpdateChart()
    Try
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "......................"
        Timer1.Interval = 3000
        Timer1.Start()
        Dim sqlStatis As String = "SELECT Top 5 Filename, Filesize FROM infofile"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatis, SQLCon)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "infofile")

        Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("infofile")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub BuildChart()
        Dim Chart1 = New Chart()
        Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
        Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
        Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()
        Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)

        ChartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1"
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
        Legend1.Name = "Legend1"
        Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1)
        Chart1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Chart1.Name = "Chart1"
        Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        Series1.Legend = "Legend1"
        Series1.Name = "Tamanho do ficheiro"
        Chart1.Series.Add(Series1)
        Chart1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(600, 300)
        Chart1.TabIndex = 0
        Chart1.Text = "Chart1"
        Chart1.Series("Tamanho do ficheiro").XValueMember = "Filename"
        Chart1.Series("Tamanho do ficheiro").YValueMembers = "Filesize"
    End Sub
```

This method will be called on the form and the data will be shown as I want. As you can see on the method I have a Timer and it will update the chart every 3 seconds or 3000 milliseconds.

Inside of the Timer I have this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    UpdateChart()
End Sub
```

And inside of the form I have this:

```
Public Sub Gráfico_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   BuildChart()
   UpdateChart()
End Sub
```

It doesn't gives me any error but it doesn't update even if I create a button called "Update Chart" and put the method already created inside of the button.

So do you have any ideia I could I solve my problem?

Comment: Separate the chart creation code from the data retrieval code and then only call the data retrieval code in the `Timer1.Tick` event.   Ideally, you create the chart once and add it once to the form.  Most likely in your current scheme, the newly added charts are behind the previous ones.

Comment: Basically creating 2 different methods, for example: one called UpdateChart and another one called CreateChart?

Comment: "Basically creating 2 different methods" -  Yes, that is the idea.  You should only need to update the chart data in your UpdateChart method.  I suggest that you declare `Chart1` at the form level so that you can easily access it in your method.

Comment: I will edit the post, then if you could see what I've done and give me some suggests......

Comment: Have you added a Chart control via the designer named Chart1?  If so, there is no need to create a new chart and add it to the form's control collection in the `BuildChart` method.  Just set the properties on that existing control.

Comment: No. This chart was created with code. It is better to add a chart control?

Comment: "It is better to add a chart control?" - It does not matter either way.  The reason I asked that question is that you are referencing a form level `Chart1` in `UpdateChart`yet you are declaring a new `Chart1` in the `BuildChart` method.  Variables declared at the method level are local to that method and can not be accessed outside the declaring method.

Comment: This isn't working. Doesn't give me any erros but it doesn't update as well. So I should declare the chart outside of everything "Dim Chart1 As New Chart() or put it just inside of the BuildChart()?

Comment: "So I should declare the chart outside of everything "Dim Chart1 As New Chart() or put it just inside of the BuildChart()?" - Declare it at the form level(i.e. not in `BuildChart`).  If this does not work, please update your post to show you code.  Also move the Timer statements from `UpdateChart` to `Gráfico_Load`.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem. Thanks for your help too

Answer (score 0):

I would move

```
   Timer1.Interval = 3000
   Timer1.Start()
```

to the end of the `Form Load`

and `Dim Chart1` as a form level variable and new it up in the `Load` as well